# using Http Module response.redirect giving ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

In my MVC web app for mobile devices I previously redirect users to `m.example.com` which worked fine.

Where as now I want to redirect to a specific page only for mobile devices since my client is not paying for mobile version and my app UI is all responsive.

When Redirected to below path then chrome gives error of "too many redirects"

```
example.com/User/NoMobile
```

My Http module is mentioned below

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequest);
    }

    private void BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = application.Context;

        //Page only for Mobile devices
        if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("https://www.example.com/User/NoMobile");
        }
    }
```

What I have tried is below, Using action/controller

```
context.Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/User/NoMobile");
```

And I also tried flat html page:

```
context.Response.Redirect("http://www.example.com/FlatPage/MobileAppNotAvailable.html");
```

However I checked that by giving google website links it works fine.

```
context.Response.Redirect("https://www.google.com/doodles/about");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `HttpModule` you can create `BaseController` and override there `OnActionExecuting` method like this:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Here you put your logic
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "User", action = "NoMobile" })); 
            return;
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Then just inherit all your controllers from this controller like this:

```
public class YourController : BaseController
```

Comment: you are right, i didn't checked the URL, but i did figured out this issue on my own and added url checking, it still not works, i think the problem is with my approach, you see the url also contains the image files that my web app uses and then it redirects them as well, which results in too many redirects (maybe), i used ActionFilter approach and it works fine, i only need to add this attribute on my every controller.

Comment: @AbubakarRiaz do you have some sort of `BaseController`, which is every of your controlles inherit from? You can override `BeginExecute` method there for every of your controllers.

Comment: That would be great, No i do not have any BaseController, can u guide/give me link?

Comment: this answer is perfect i only changed this `filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "User", action = "NoMobile" }));
                //filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("https://www.example.com/User/NoMobile");
                //return;`